# Connecting Yamaha KX8 Keyboard to computer?

Tags: windows, linux, usb, keyboard, music

EDIT: SORRY it was not p80 but KX8!

Update: I found the name of my software that came with keyboard:  Cubase Ai4

How can I connect usb-piano to my computer?

I recently bought a yamaha KX8 keyboard. It does not, however, have any built in speakers, but must be connected to something in order to play.

It come with a USB cord and some weird windows software, that must be running in order for the keyboard to make any sound. Now that software seems VERY complicated. I merely want to play the "piano" instrument.

I was wandering if there is some kind of SIMPLER software (maybe open source) that will allow me to connect this keyboard to either windows or linux os?

I have no knowledge of the music jargon, so all the buzz words on the music forums go over my head. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit* In retrospect, I'm not really sure that I've answered your question, since lmms is not necessarily any simpler than your windows software, and I'm not aware of anything that's very simple to install that will just give you a piano sound without some configuration.  But if you end up needing to learn more about this stuff in order to get what you want, this may prove a useful starting point.

Under linux or windows, you can use [lmms](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/): this is a free-as-in-speech "digital audio workstation" (DAW).  It's a bit more than just a way to play piano sounds, but is fairly easy to set up and use.  The [getting started guide](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=0.4:Getting_Started) is a good place to, er, start.  If you're very new to this, it's probably worth spending an hour or so reading through the [manual](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=0.4:Manual).  There are some other guides, on installation for example, at [their main wiki page](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).

#### DAWs

I'm not aware of anything under windows that's more specifically geared to the task of playing piano sounds; in general this is done by DAWs, which provide a management interface for hooking up various sound generators to make piano sounds, drumkit sounds, vintage synth sounds, never-before-heard-sounds, and many more.  They also provide the ability to *sequence* (program) the playing of samples at particular pitches, volumes, etc., to create melodies, rhythms, and entire pieces of music that can be played back and edited.  You can also layer effects on top of your tracks, generate a musical score, and do other interesting things.

#### `rosegarden`

I personally prefer [rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/) to lmms as a DAW under linux, but I think it's a bit less beginner-friendly; for instance, it doesn't include any sound generator plugins like qsynth ("synths"), but expects you to install them and link it up with them.  lmms includes a couple, so it lowers the learning curve a bit.  One advantage of rosegarden that may interest you as a piano player is the option to program music by scoring it using traditional staff notation.  I'm not sure if lmms provides this facility.  Note that rosegarden is only available for linux.

#### `qsynth`

Under linux, there are more specifically-targeted programs, like [qsynth](http://qsynth.sourceforge.net/qsynth-index.html), that do one thing and do it well; in qsynth's case, this task is to play sampled sounds at various pitches, including, IIRC, some decently realistic piano sounds (lmms I think has one or two of these as well).  However, because programs like qsynth are built as components rather than an applications, you'll need some understanding of the infrastructure in order to use them.  DAWs like lmms or rosegarden are designed to help manage that infrastructure, but if you want a more stripped-down system, you can run the synth programs without a DAW.

#### JACK

In addition, the [JACK Audio Connection Kit](http://jackaudio.org/) is required by many linux music production programs (lmms excluded)  JACK is a sound server like ALSA (linux's default sound server) that is very low-latency and provides, via `qjackctl`, an interface to hook synths up to MIDI inputs (like your keyboard) and sound outputs (like your soundcard).  If you have JACK installed under linux, you can use qsynth directly with it, without needing to use a DAW.  Installing it under most distros is mostly just a matter of installing the package, though you may have to do a bit of delving to get it running entirely smoothly.  You have to start it up before you can run it; this is also done with the GUI app `qjackctl`.  Depending on your distro, you might need to install the package `qjackctl` in addition to the `jackd` package.  These package names are themselves specific to the ubuntu distribution, but common among some others in the debian family.

#### Latency

Again, because LMMS can use ALSA drivers interchangeably with JACK drivers, JACK is not a requirement to use it.  However, when using ALSA drivers, the latency will be higher.  Low latency is important because it means that sounds come out of the speakers *as* you play the keyboard, rather than a noticeable amount of time afterwards.  Annoying latency is maybe about a tenth of a second; some systems under Windows or using ALSA will stick you with twice that or more.  JACK will get you very low latency sound, to the point where it's not noticeable at all.  This is possible under Windows as well, but you may have to tune your system or use a different sound card or driver.

#### ubuntu studio

If you're considering installing linux specifically in order to do music production, you may be well off to use a distro geared towards that.  This will take care of the details of setting up JACK, installing a DAW, etc., and provide you with a slew of synths and other related apps to explore.  I've found [ubuntu studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) to be pretty solid; there are some other options listed in the ["External links" section of its wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntustudio#External_links).  If you really just want to use your keyboard as a piano, you may find the volume of options it provides overwhelming, but if you want to explore more possibilities later, it will make that very convenient.

#### `vkeybd`

Finally, if you do have trouble getting things working under linux, the [virtual keyboard plugin](http://packages.debian.org/stable/sound/vkeybd) can be helpful to figure out if the problem is with your software setup or with the interface with your keyboard.  This will be installed with ubuntu studio, and probably with the other multimedia-oriented distros; otherwise you can install that package to get it.

Comment: Wow, Thanks, I was actually looking for something like this - that gives me an overview of what goes where.

Comment: What you are saying about latency is true about my windows daw program that came with a keyboard. When I press the key on the keyboard it takes 1/2 to 1 second to hear it on my headphones. I thought it was normal, and also very annoying.

Comment: Also I found what the software is called "Cubase Ai4 and editor software is included"

Comment: Yes, your suggestion about installing ubuntu studio is nice. I may take a notebook and set it up near my keyboard. Great suggestion!

Comment: Cool!  Your latency issue might be resolvable through a setting in there.  The full version of Cubase is certainly capable of this and much more, provided your sound card supports it.  I'm unfamiliar with Ai4 but generally the software packaged with gear is not full-featured, unless maybe if it's top of the line gear.  But even so it's likely that you just need to tweak a setting to get that working.

Comment: Ok, i plugged in my keyboard. nothing happens. What's more - the rosegarden and lmms are really slow and buggy on my laptop, and neither of them makes a sound. I am a programmer and really surprised at how complex this process of connecting the digital instrument to a computer is!

Comment: I have no idea the steps which I should take. I found this guide, but it never actually says how to PLAY or hear some sound: http://www.64studio.com/manual/audio/rosegarden

Comment: Hmm.. Are you able to use vkeybd in place of your keyboard?  If that works, and your keyboard doesn't, it could be an issue with drivers.  maybe check on ubuntuforums (assuming you're running ubuntu studio) for information on that particular keyboard or family of keyboards.  I have an older M-audio keyboard that requires a special package to be installed, but if it's installed it just works.

Comment: On the other hand, if you can't get sound via vkeybd it could be that there's something you need to set up.  Rosegarden and I think also lmms will show something lighting up when you press a key, so if that happens but the volume levels don't change, you know that you need to set the keyboard up as a MIDI input, or maybe configure an instrument for that track.  If you see levels but get no sound, then you might have to route the audio output from the DAW to your sound card (though normally it will be set up like this by default).

Comment: You can also try using `lsusb -v` from the command line to get a listing of USB devices, to verify that it's actually seeing your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks intuited... the thing is that I can actually see my keyboard in the midi-preference of rosegarden if I dig around. But it does not make rosegarden respond or make any sounds. It's just that  I don't know how to setup the keyboard as midi, because the guide shows options different than the current version of Rosegarden provides...

Comment: Are you able to hook up the `vkeybd` keyboard to make sounds in Rosegarden?  ie is it something specific to your keyboard, or is it just an issue with figuring out Rosegarden?   .......  I usually rig things up through `qjackctl` rather than doing it in rosegarden; you should see your keyboard listed as an output in the 'MIDI' tab of `qjackctl` (the second tab).  You just hook it up to a rosegarden input via click-drag.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec page](http://music.yamaha.com/products/specifications.html?productId=659&hierarchy_id=16365_16277) for the P-80, it has speakers and an amp built in. Is this not the keyboard you are using?

In any event, yes, you need special software within Windows for Windows to recognize this keyboard via USB and actually play sound from it. This would be called "[MIDI Sequencer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_sequencer)" software, and there are a variety of packages available for all budgets -- from free or open source all the way through very expensive professional-grade packages.

Generally, MIDI sequencing software is designed such that you can record and playback your performance, and often "multi-track" record. This would allow you to, say, record the piano track, then lay down a bass track over that, then a guitar track, all from your keyboard. You'd then be able to remix the song as needed.

Comment: SORRY! I meant KX8! I just came home - I thought it was p80, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

It may act as a USB MIDI device. If so then you can run a software sequencer to listen to the MIDI messages and play the audio.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought one and got the Cubase software. I even bought the tutorial CD and still no luck. I get sounds from the midi port but it's limited.

Downloaded Linux Multi Media studio and that got me going its much simpler. Since I am not into looping, and all the fancy stuff to create a beat, it's ok for me. I like the drums too.